# Is there a way to include a Condition to adquire method in java (or scala) Semaphore object?

Tags: java, scala, locking, semaphore, synchronization

I have a program that holds many threads, lets put as an example six threads. Five of them should be able to use concurrently a given resource but the last thread shouldn't if a given condition occurs and should wait until that condition is over.

In my understanding a ReentrantLock can't be used because it can only be held by one thread at a time. In the other hand a Semaphore can be held by many threads at a time but I can't find a way to attach the condition to aquire method.

Can This high level objects do the trick or I will have to implement this functionality using notify and wait directly?

Eg.

```
class A{
   getResource{ ... }
}

//This Runable could be spawn many times at the same time
class B implements Runnable{
   run {
      setConditionToTrue
      getResource
      ...
      getResource
      ...
      getResource
      setConditionToFalse
   }
}

//This will be working forever but only one Thread
class C implements Runnable{
   run{
      loop{
         if(Condition == true) wait
         getResource
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance pals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am restating your problem here: You want your B threads to access the shared resource concurrently, but your C thread should wait for some condition to occur before using the resource.

If I understand your question correctly, You can use `ReentrantLock` to solve your problem.

Introduce a new function called `getAccess()` and make the C thread call this function to get the shared resource. Introduce two more functions to allow and stop the access to shared resource.

```
class A {

  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private Condition someCondition = lock.newCondition();
  private boolean bCondition = false;

  getResource{ ... } // Your existing method used by B threads

  getAccess() { // Protected access to some resource, called by C thread
    lock.acquire();

    try {
      if (!bCondition)
        someCondition.await(); // B thread will wait here but releases the lock
    } finally {
      lock.release();
    }
  }

  allowAccess() { // B thread can call this func to notify C and allow access
    lock.acquire();
    try {
      bCondition = true;
      someCondition.signal(); // Decided to release the resource
    } finally {
      lock.release();
    }
  }

  stopAccess() { // B thread can stop the access
    lock.acquire();
    try {
      bCondition = false;
    } finally {
      lock.release();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: If thread B#1 calls stopAccess() and start doing his work and before it ends B#2 calls again stopAccess() B#2 will be blocked rigth? If that the case this wont work because I need to have running a large amount of Bs at the same time without locking.

Comment: B#1 calls stopAccess(), flips the boolean and releases the lock immediately, so B#2 or any other thread call stopAccess() and they won't be blocked.

Comment: Yes you are completly right. This will work. Thank you sperumal

Answer (score 0):

If you want several threads to share a resource, you need to be more specific about the meaning of that sharing. Normally this means differentiating between those threads that *read* the current value of the resource and other threads that *change* the value. This implies is a concurrent-read / exclusive-write pattern ('crew') if the writes are to be race-free and stable.

In the Java API, this is provided by the [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). There are also other alternatives worthy of consideration, such as the carefully-implemented [Crew](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/jcsp-1.1-rc4/jcsp-doc/org/jcsp/lang/Crew.html) in JCSP.

Using [J]CSP, a different pattern is also available: that of wrapping the common resource in its own thread and providing access to it via a shared JCSP channel from all the client threads. This client-server pattern is easy to understand and implement, and has the added benefit that it is formally deadlock-free, given that the thread communication graph is acyclic ([more](http://wotug.ukc.ac.uk/parallel/theory/formal/csp/jeremy-martin/)).

Comment: Thanks Rick, yes like you mention what I need is write access. I would like to keep using core libraries to solve this issue so I will stick to sperumal solution.